# MongoDB Full Text Search with JHIPSTER / SPRING DATA MONGODB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, jhipster, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to do some full text queries with the last release  of jhîpster (4.0.7) and spring data mongodb.

I created a repository which extends CrudRepository:

```
public interface PublicSearchRepository extends CrudRepository<Transcriptionrequest, String> {

  Page<Transcriptionrequest> findBy(TextCriteria textCriteria, Pageable pageable);
```

and apply the query as following :

```
TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().caseSensitive(Boolean.FALSE);
        textCriteria.matching(query);

Page<Transcriptionrequest> page = publicSearchRepository.findBy(textCriteria, pageable);
```

My object is indexed with the annotations

```
@Document(collection = "transcriptionrequest")
public class Transcriptionrequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @TextScore
    private Float score;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("request_id")
    private String request_id;

    @NotNull
    @Field("song_name")
    @TextIndexed(weight = 2)
    private String song_name;
```

When I try to search,I always have this error :

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 4 and error message 'Missing expected field "$search"' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 4 and error message 'Missing expected field "$search"' on server localhost:27017
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2134)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1977)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1783)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1766)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:640)
```

When I raised the log level of mongo classes I have the query. The search field is never sent.

```
Created query Query: { }, Fields: null, Sort: null
2017-03-02 22:53:45.625 DEBUG 6428 --- [ XNIO-2 task-20] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "$text" : { "$caseSensitive" : false}} fields: { "score" : { "$meta" : "textScore"}} for class: class info.touret.songtranscriptmarket.domain.Transcriptionrequest in collection: transcriptionrequest
2017-03-02 22:53:45.626 DEBUG 6428 --- [ XNIO-2 task-20] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[songtranscriptmarket]
```

How can I fix that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add the code where you are creating `TextCriteria` obj ? and what is your spring mongo db version?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post with the textcriteria creation

Comment: `TextCriteria` creation parts looks good and just to make sure the `query` is a matching value and has a valid value right ?

Comment: I use spring-data-mongodb 1.10.0-RELEASE . It's bundled with jhipster

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem. The query parameter was null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My query was equal to null.
In this case the framework doesn't fill the $search attribute.